# Windows 10 Freezes when Idle after a few days

Tags: windows, windows-10, freeze

I am having issues with a computer that I can't seem to figure out. I have an HP Compaq 8200 Elite SFF that freezes at random whenever the PC goes idle. We only use it for internet and files. No games or anything like that. It's out in a warehouse, which isn't an ideal place for a computer, but our warehouse workers need to use it. I went to clock in this morning on this computer and the computer had locked up. I had to do a hard reset to get the computer back on and working again.

I have tried running troubleshooting, SFC & DISM scans in command prompt, device manager scan, registry scan through CCleaner, clean boot and countless other things all of which I've had no luck. I have reason to believe this is a hardware problem. I've tried to find the drivers for the motherboard, but HP doesn't provide them.

The last thing I want to do is reinstall Windows. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you check to see if there is an updated BIOS for the motherboard?

Comment: I'd like to, but there's no way to check this as HP doesn't supply BIOS updates.

Comment: Not according to my Internet, maybe yours is different :) https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-compaq-elite-8300-small-form-factor-pc/5232852/swItemId/vc-214334-1

Comment: Just to confirm: According to CPU-Z, I'm running version J01 v02.06. From what you sent me, I'm assuming it sounds like it needs an update

Comment: That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: I tried running it and it says it isn't compatible.

Comment: Should be right, but there is a note in the release notes that states: "Version: v02.99 Rev.A

Fixed in this release: - Customers MUST flash this BIOS first, before flashing to the v03.xx versions."

Comment: The message on my screen reads "The BIOS image is not compatible with this system. Family of BIOS in ROM update: K01 Family of BIOS in system: J01 The system BIOS will not be updated."

Comment: You positive it is not the 8200 Elite?

Comment: I just double checked and yes, it IS in fact the 8200 Elite SFF. My apologies.

Comment: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/swdetails/hp-compaq-8200-elite-convertible-minitower-pc/5037949/swItemId/vc-213791-1

Comment: I just tried again using the new file and it completed successfully.

Comment: Have you tested/replaced the hard drive?  Maybe even put an SSD in it.  We had 8200/8300 and we are disposing of them as fast as we can.

Comment: Does the machine still have the issue?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean At the moment, I am unsure. I double checked the wiring in the cabinet where the PC is located. It turns out that there is a 12V power supply connected to the power box that the PC is plugged into. This power supply controls an external fan which we've never really had to use. We took these wires out of the power box and capped them off. My thoughts are that there is some kind of interference coming from the power supply that the power box doesn't like. Hopefully, this fixes the issue. If it works well after a few days, I'll mark as answered. If not, I'll let you know.

Comment: @cybernard I have run various scans to the hard drive and the OS itself. Everything is telling me the computer is healthy. My thoughts now tell me that it has to be a wiring problem.

Comment: Jeremy, can you confirm that the wiring was the problem ? I have the same problem with some HP 8200. I found more people on forums, but no solution. Power led remains solid green, no HDD activity, no response on LAN, video (blank), USB, etc

Comment: @adrianTNT Yes, the answer I posted below worked in my situation. It's not a good idea to split power between computers as it can affect the computer's performance. If your PCs are in cabinets like mine were, you might want to check the wiring of the cabinet if there's an outlet inside of it. Otherwise, there may be another problem.

Comment: I tested 2 HP 8200 and when I had them in same socket, I saw them both frozen after 1-2 days of work. When they were separate, they froze individually :) Their PSU might be sensitive.

Comment: @adrianTNT That sounds more like a processing problem to me. What are they being used for and what all is running on them? You may need to upgrade some hardware...

Comment: It runs web servers and database servers, but is strange that sometimes they fail at once. E.g. they run for 7 days straight and then stop responding in same day, maybe even same hour but I don't always notice it immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so here's what's happened so far.
I've added this as an answer because it seemed to work for me, although it's a unique situation. Apparently, this is a super weird issue I've never seen before.

So to explain the situation: The computer in question sits inside our warehouse outside of our Production Manager's office. This computer would freeze when it went idle at a random time, usually when not in use for an extended period of time (say, over the weekend). I would only notice this every few days or when I came back from the previous weekend. The computer in question is an HP Compaq Elite 8200 SFF running Windows 10 with a 1TB HDD, 8GB RAM, and integrated graphics. There is also a computer not far away on the other side of the shop that houses an identical computer of the same model. However, this one runs Windows 7, not Windows 10. This is the only difference between the two. I took the Win10 computer back to my office and connected it to one of my monitors running all kinds of scans including Windows Updates, chkdsk, SFC & DISM scans, registry scans via CCleaner, device manager scans, clean boot, troubleshooting power and system maintenance, updated the BIOS, and ran memory diagnostic checks. Everything I did, the computer gave me no errors or problems of any kind and everything appeared to work as it should. The computer was 100% functional and operating as normal. So why was it working just fine at my desk, but not out in the warehouse?

Here's the solution I discovered: Both of the computers sit inside an orange cabinet on the wall with a monitor, keyboard, mouse and USB WiFi adapter for Internet that sit above it on a small shelf. This is so the people in our warehouse can clock in and out of the jobs they work on. Both the computer and monitor are plugged into a power box which is connected to another power cord which is plugged into an outlet, giving power to the whole cabinet. Inside the cabinet where the computer sits is an external power supply specifically for LEDs (Mean Well LPV-20-12). This power supply was wired into the power box that the computer is plugged into. Since the power supply can provide 12V, the LED power supply was used to power an external fan inside the cabinet (although, we've never used it). The Win7 cabinet did not have the power supply wired up to the power receptacle, but the cabinet with the Win10 computer did. So last week, we took the power box apart and removed the LED power supply connections from the receptacle capping the wires off. So far, the computer is working normally as expected. If possible, I'd like to use the external fan, but I'd rather power it through USB instead of another power supply.

In layman's terms, I think it was some kind of power interference. I am not an electrician, so I have no idea how this worked. I invite you to leave a comment if you know what happened.

Answer (score 2):

HP doesn't [supply](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-compaq-elite-8300-small-form-factor-pc/5232852) these drivers, so they come from Windows.

I would suggest to:

1. Check the Event Viewer for explanatory messages
2. Watch temperature sensors for CPU and GPU, for example using
   [HWMonitor](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html)
3. Give the computer a good clean, and if CPU temperature is a problem renew
   thermal paste
4. If all fails, maybe it's time for a new computer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90225/discussion-on-answer-by-harrymc-windows-10-freezes-when-idle-after-a-few-days).